# Laravel 8 not finding any route in web.php

Tags: php, laravel

So here's a new one for me. I'm a pretty experienced Laravel developer and was working on a project today. It's a pretty big project and it's been working up until now. However, I walked away from my desk for lunch today and when I came back, I started getting these errors. Let's pretend someone messed with me while I was gone, I can't find another reason for this.

The error can basically be described as this: no route in my web.php file works. I get this strange result in the chrome debuggar:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Illuminate\Support\Facades\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController] does not exist.
```

What's interesting about it is that it's trying to prepend `Illuminate\Support\Facades` to the beginning of the namespace of the controller. Again, NO idea how this started happening.

The story gets MORE interesting. as the first route of my file, I just put a callback function:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
   

Route::get('/test', function(){
    return 123;
});
```

This results in a 404 error. The app doesn't even find that route.

**Things I've tried:**

uncommenting the `protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';` in the `RouteServiceProvider.php`

using laravel 7 syntax of `Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@index');`

adding `use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController` to the top of the file

None of these solutions seemed to have helped at all as I'm still getting this error. Can anyone offer some advice?

**Added AutoLoad from Composer.json**

```
  "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
```

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
    protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

Comment: You have a namespace issue. `Illuminate\Support\Facades\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController` seems to be incorrect. Can you please include your routes file or section of it?

Comment: How do I fix this issue and what file is it located in?

Comment: did you cache your routes?

Comment: Yes, I've run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: that wouldn't clear the route cache if it was cached

Comment: @BrianThompson, the route file that I included in the question is my actual route file

Comment: Try the full path: `Route::get('/test', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index']);`. Be sure the namespace in the `RouteProvider` is null or removed for this.

Comment: Yes that's how I was originally doing it and how all my routes were formatted until this error started happening. It happens with the "action" syntax like in your comment as well as with the "classic" syntax from laravel 7

Comment: that's why I as asking for you to put it in the question. All that's in the question is the closure route. Did you put a namespace in your routes file accidentally?

Comment: ah i see, here is the route right under my test closure: `Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');`. the `use` statements in the question are all that's there. no accidental namespaces. unless the first line of `Facades\App` shouldn't be there. but even when I comment that out, it still gives the same error

Comment: What does your composer.json look like under `autoload`?

Comment: @maximus1127 also notice I had a beginning \ before `App`.

Comment: i just updated question to include autoload from composer.json

Comment: can you provide the `RouteServiceProvider@boot` definition?

Comment: question updated to include

Answer (score 0):

So, based on @lagbox comment above, I ran `php artisan config:cache` which then resolved my original error. However, I then received a new one stating this:

`Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()`

All other questions online told me that to get rid of this error, I had to delete `config.php` from `bootstrap/cache` directory. But I didn't have one! After further digging, in Laravel 8 you just have to rename the `routes-v7.php` file to something else. I chose to rename it to `routes-v7-please-work.php` and lo, my app works again now. no idea how this all happened but thanks to the ones who responded and got me on the right track.

If I'm missing any steps to recovering from this based on the things I described above, please let me know. Things such as extra artisan commands or something to reoptimize things or other tips.